# Postcode / Zip Code wildcard search WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, wildcard

I basically need to add a Postcode input field on a WooCommerce product page to check an item is available in that area before the product is added to the cart. I was wondering whether anyone might be able to suggest a suitable plugin which uses Wildcard pattern matching or similar?

Either that or whether anyone knows whether it is possible to use the Postcode input field from the checkout page within the woocommerce product page?

Answer (score 0):

Best plugin as per your requirement : [WooCommerce Restrict / Check COD based on PIN / ZIP / Postal codes](http://gremlin.io/shop/woocommerce-plugins/restrict-check-cod-payment-method-zip-pin-codes-woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I have spoken to the developers of this plugin and it doesn't support wildcard pattern matching which would mean I would have to find and add thousands of postcodes rather than just the first few letters

Comment: Ahh ok. Refer it if can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909264/woocommerce-check-zip-code-before-placing-order